# Выбрать radiobutton и подтвердить выбор

Tags: python, http, request, urllib

Есть тест, с такой структурой:

```
Вопрос
 ответ1
 ответ2
 ответ4
 ответ5
Submitbutton
```

Мне нужно выбрать только первый вариант и подтвердить.

Форма вопроса:

```html
<div class="formulation clearfix"><h4 class="accesshide">Текст питання</h4><input type="hidden" name="q1435804:1_:sequencecheck" value="1"><div class="qtext">SQL (Structured query language - мова структурованих запитів), складається з наступних груп:</div><div class="ablock"><div class="prompt">Виберіть одну відповідь:</div><div class="answer"><div class="r0"><input type="radio" name="q1435804:1_answer" value="0" id="q1435804:1_answer0"><label for="q1435804:1_answer0">a. DDL, DML, DCL, TCL</label> </div>
<div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q1435804:1_answer" value="1" id="q1435804:1_answer1"><label for="q1435804:1_answer1">b. інша відповідь</label> </div>
<div class="r0"><input type="radio" name="q1435804:1_answer" value="2" id="q1435804:1_answer2"><label for="q1435804:1_answer2">c. DML, UCL, DSL, TCL</label> </div>
<div class="r1"><input type="radio" name="q1435804:1_answer" value="3" id="q1435804:1_answer3"><label for="q1435804:1_answer3">d. DDL, UML, DSL, TCL</label> </div>
<div class="r0"><input type="radio" name="q1435804:1_answer" value="4" id="q1435804:1_answer4"><label for="q1435804:1_answer4">e. DDL, DCL, USL, TCL</label> </div>
</div></div><div class="im-controls"><input type="submit" id="q1435804:1_-submit" name="q1435804:1_-submit" value="Відмітити" class="submit btn"></div></div>
```

Comment: в чём вопрос? как послать http-запрос в Питоне? Как закодировать значение формы?

Comment: @jfs Прощу прощение за столь короткую инфу. Вот сылка на англоязычный стак, я там все подробно обьяснил. [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37469280/check-the-radio-and-submit-it)